# why method = 'curl' is not working in download.file in R?

Tags: r, curl

I am working in R.I want to download an excel file from web and I am using download.file command:

```
download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx",
          destfile="data/ExcelExample.xlsx",method='curl')
```

But when I try to run the code it displays an error as:

> download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx",
>   +               destfile="data/ExcelExample.xlsx",method='curl')
>   Error in download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx",  : 
>     'curl' call had nonzero exit status.

Comment: The problem is the ```destfile``` argument. Does this folder exist or do you have rights to write there? For testing your code you can remove the destfile argument.

Comment: Folder exist and I can also download other files at the same location but only this one is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link redirects via an http 301 response to an https address, which `method = "curl"` seems not to like. The "internal" and "wget" methods don't work either.

I'm using Windows and I seem to get away without specifying a method at all - according to the manual the default is "auto", which presumably chooses the most appropriate method for you. In my case this appears to give the same result as `method = "wininet"`, though `method = "libcurl"` works too.

If you're using not Windows, try removing `method="curl"` and it should work fine. Otherwise, try `method = "libcurl"`.

You can see I can replicate your error even though I have a valid file path.

```r
download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx", 
              path.expand("~/jared.xlsx"), method = "curl")
# Error in download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx",  : 
#   'curl' call had nonzero exit status
```

But I can get it to work by just removing "method" altogether.

```r
download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx", 
              path.expand("~/jared.xlsx"))
# trying URL 'https://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx'
# Content type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats' length 2045364 bytes (2.0 MB)
# downloaded 2.0 MB
```

Comment: File has downloaded but the new problem is that file is not working and i cannot able to open it in R.

Comment: How are you trying to open it Rohit? What error is it giving you?

Comment: The code i am trying to run is:library(readxl)
excel_sheets("C:/Users/PC/Documents/jared.xlsx")

Comment: It gives output as:  excel_sheets("C:/Users/PC/Documents/jared.xlsx")
Error: Evaluation error: error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo
.

Comment: @Rohit when you download.file, can you try `download.file(url = "http://www.jaredlander.com/data/ExcelExample.xlsx", "C:/Users/PC/Documents/jared.xlsx", mode = "wb")` so that the file is saved in binary. It should open now.